# How to read this phrase/sentence?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

the headline is: 'slip sliding away from history' source: NY Times

If slip and slide means the same thing how to read that?

Answer (score 4):

The phrase is a reference to 'Slip Slidin' Away', a famous 1978 song by Simon and Garfunkel. The use of 'slip' and 'sliding' is an example of poetic repetition, common in songs and poems. One action or event is described by two words instead of one.

[Slip Sidin' Away (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rGDzbV75EI)